# Trying to write a setdiff() function using RcppArmadillo gives compilation error

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, armadillo

I'm trying to write a sort of analogue of R's setdiff() function in C++ using RcppArmadillo. My rather crude approach:

```
  // [[Rcpp::export]]
  arma::uvec my_setdiff(arma::uvec x, arma::uvec y){
  // Coefficientes of unsigned integer vector y form a subset of the coefficients of unsigned integer vector x.
  // Returns set difference between the coefficients of x and those of y
  int n2 = y.n_elem;
  uword q1;
  for (int j=0 ; j<n2 ; j++){
    q1 = find(x==y[j]);
    x.shed_row(q1);
  }
  return x;
  }
```

fails at compilation time. The error reads:

```
fnsauxarma.cpp:622:29: error: no matching function for call to ‘arma::Col<double>::shed_row(const arma::mtOp<unsigned int, arma::mtOp<unsigned int, arma::Col<double>, arma::op_rel_eq>,     arma::op_find>)’
```

I really have no idea what's going on, any help or comments would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [_"(member functions of Mat, Col and SpMat)"_](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Col) `shed_row()` is probably not a member function of `arma::uvec`.

Comment: The line `q1 = find(x==y[j])` is wrong. The output of [find()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#find) is always [uvec](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Col), not uword.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `arma::find` returns a `uvec`, and doesn't know how to make the implicit conversion to `arma::uword`, as pointed out by @mtall. You can help the compiler out by using the templated `arma::conv_to<T>::from()` function. Also, I included another version of `my_setdiff` that returns an `Rcpp::NumericVector` because although the first version returns the correct values, it's technically a `matrix` (i.e. it has dimensions), and I assume you would want this to be as compatible with R's `setdiff` as possible. This is accomplished by setting the `dim` attribute of the return vector to `NULL`, using `R_NilValue` and the `Rcpp::attr` member function.

---

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::uvec my_setdiff(arma::uvec& x, const arma::uvec& y){

  for (size_t j = 0; j < y.n_elem; j++) {
    arma::uword q1 = arma::conv_to<arma::uword>::from(arma::find(x == y[j]));
    x.shed_row(q1);
  }
  return x;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector my_setdiff2(arma::uvec& x, const arma::uvec& y){

  for (size_t j = 0; j < y.n_elem; j++) {
    arma::uword q1 = arma::conv_to<arma::uword>::from(arma::find(x == y[j]));
    x.shed_row(q1);
  }

  Rcpp::NumericVector x2 = Rcpp::wrap(x);
  x2.attr("dim") = R_NilValue;
  return x2;
}

/*** R
x <- 1:8
y <- 2:6

R> all.equal(setdiff(x,y), my_setdiff(x,y))
#[1] "Attributes: < target is NULL, current is list >" "target is numeric, current is matrix"           

R> all.equal(setdiff(x,y), my_setdiff2(x,y))
#[1] TRUE

R> setdiff(x,y)
#[1] 1 7 8

R> my_setdiff(x,y)
# [,1]
# [1,]    1
# [2,]    7
# [3,]    8

R> my_setdiff2(x,y)
#[1] 1 7 8

*/
```

---

**Edit:** 
For the sake of completeness, here is a more robust version of `setdiff` than the two implementations presented above:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector arma_setdiff(arma::uvec& x, arma::uvec& y){

    x = arma::unique(x);
    y = arma::unique(y);

    for (size_t j = 0; j < y.n_elem; j++) {
        arma::uvec q1 = arma::find(x == y[j]);
        if (!q1.empty()) {
            x.shed_row(q1(0));
        }
    }

    Rcpp::NumericVector x2 = Rcpp::wrap(x);
    x2.attr("dim") = R_NilValue;
    return x2;
}

/*** R

x <- 1:10
y <- 2:8

R> all.equal(setdiff(x,y), arma_setdiff(x,y))
#[1] TRUE

X <- 1:6
Y <- c(2,2,3)

R> all.equal(setdiff(X,Y), arma_setdiff(X,Y))
#[1] TRUE
*/
```

---

The previous versions would throw an error if you passed them vectors with non-unique elements, e.g.

```
R> my_setdiff2(X,Y)

error: conv_to(): given object doesn't have exactly one element
```

To solve the problem and more closely mirror R's `setdiff`, we just make `x` and `y` unique. Additionally, I switched out the `arma::conv_to<>::from` with `q1(0)` (where `q1` is now a `uvec` instead of a `uword`), because `uvec`'s are just a vector of `uword`s, and the explicit cast seemed a little inelegant.

Comment: This does not work as expected. For instance, `arma_setdiff(10:13, 4:5)`  throws an error for me: `Error in arma_setdiff(10:13, 4:5) : Mat::operator(): index out of bounds`

Comment: @Johan Larsson fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [std::set_difference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_difference/) from the STL instead, converting back and forth from arma::uvec.

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <algorithm>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::uvec std_setdiff(arma::uvec& x, arma::uvec& y) {

  std::vector<int> a = arma::conv_to< std::vector<int> >::from(arma::sort(x));
  std::vector<int> b = arma::conv_to< std::vector<int> >::from(arma::sort(y));
  std::vector<int> out;

  std::set_difference(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end(),
                      std::inserter(out, out.end()));

  return arma::conv_to<arma::uvec>::from(out);
}
```

**Edit:** I thought a performance comparison might be in order. The difference becomes smaller when the relative sizes of the sets are in the opposite order.

```
a <- sample.int(350)
b <- sample.int(150)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(std_setdiff(a, b), arma_setdiff(a, b))

> Unit: microseconds
>                expr    min      lq     mean median     uq     max neval cld
>   std_setdiff(a, b) 11.548 14.7545 17.29930 17.107 19.245  36.779   100  a 
>  arma_setdiff(a, b) 60.727 65.0040 71.77804 66.714 72.702 138.133   100   b
```

Answer (score 0):

The Questioner might have already got the answer. However, the following template version may be more general. This is equivalent to [setdiff](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setdiff.html) function in Matlab

If P and Q are two sets, then their difference is given by P - Q or Q - P. If `P = {1, 2, 3, 4}` and `Q = {4, 5, 6}`, P - Q means elements of P which are not in Q. i.e., in the above example P - Q = {1, 2, 3}.

```
/* setdiff(t1, t2) is similar to setdiff() function in MATLAB. It removes the common elements and
   gives the uncommon elements in the vectors t1 and t2. */


template <typename T>
T setdiff(T t1, T t2)
{
    int size_of_t1 = size(t1);
    int size_of_t2 = size(t2);

    T Intersection_Elements;
    uvec iA, iB;
    intersect(Intersection_Elements, iA, iB, t1, t2);

    for (int i = 0; i < size(iA); i++)
    {
        t1(iA(i)) = 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size(iB); i++)
    {
        t2(iB(i)) = 0;
    }

    T t1_t2_vec(size_of_t1 + size_of_t2);
    t1_t2_vec = join_vert(t1, t2);
    T DiffVec = nonzeros(t1_t2_vec);


    return DiffVec;
}
```

Any suggestions for improving the performance of the algorithm are welcome.